# Indexing when working with cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have 3x2 cell array called `signals`. All cells contain a 8x6xN array full of integers. I am trying to move down every row by one row and overwrite the first row with NaNs. Howevery, I am struggling with the correct syntax regarding indexing. I am able to manipulate one particular cell like this:

```
signals{1,1}(2:end, :) = signals{1,1}(1:end-1, :);
signals{1,1}(1,:) = NaN;
```

How can I apply this manipulation to the whole cell array? I am basically looking for something like this:

```
signals{:}(2:end, :) = signals{:}(1:end-1, :);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through each element in the cell array and perform the operation on each of these elements.

```
for k = 1:numel(signals)
    signals{k}(2:end, :) = signals{k}(1:end-1, :);
    signals{k}(1,:) = NaN;
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to solve that problem without using a loop. I am looking for the most efficient way in terms of speed as the `signals` matrix may become quite large.

Comment: @Andi No. Thanks to JIT acceleration, the performance penalty for using a loop such as this is minimal. Also, if you really want performance, then I would use a multi-dimensional array rather than a cell array if possible.